# How often to call DataContext.SubmitChanges() for a large number of inserts?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

How many `InsertOnSubmit` should I call before calling `SubmitChanges`? I'm adding data from a web service that can return tens of thousands of records one record at a time. The wrapper class around the web service exposes the records a an `IEnumberable` collection to hide an elaborate chunking mechanism.

Are there guidelines on how many inserts I should accumulate before submitting them?

Comment: I had the same problem, and spent ages searching for an answer. In the end, this was my lifesaver... enjoy.
http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/LINQ/InsertAndDeletes.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also depends on the kind of data you need to insert. Sometimes I need to insert a lot of records, where I also need the ID of, to insert more records in another table.

Because the ID gets assigned when you submit changes to the database, I need to call SubmitChanges on specific times.

When this is not needed, I just submit them with a 1000 at once or so (depending on the total number of records I need to insert).

Maybe you could do some speed tests, which are best for you. Depending on the hardware, expectations of amount of records, etc.

Comment: That's a good point regarding getting an ID back. I'm concerned about the memory footprint as there can be some large records but 1000 at a time is a good place to start.

Comment: Yup, that is one thing I really hate about it. Sometimes each record needs a new ID, which makes you submit records way to much for a good performance. This is something you need to figure out in your code, just to see where you need them and where you can submit them later.

Answer (score 4):

For making changes to one field for 1000 records in batch vs 1 at a time: 1 record at a time takes 0.1989 sec/record vs batch which takes 0.0711 sec/record. So Batch is about 3x as fast in my tests. Note that the batch sizes vary in efficiency.

submitchanges() 1 record at a time
**records   sec sec/record**
**1000      198.95  0.1989**

Batch submitchanges()
**records   sec sec/record  % change**
100     12.20   0.1220      133%
200     18.33   0.0916      122%
500     37.59   0.0752      106%
**1,000     71.07   0.0711      103%**
2,000       138.64  0.0693      102%
10,000      680.36  0.0680

Answer (score 3):

Well i've done it with hundreds of thousands of records across multiple tables in the one go without a problem.  In fact, whereas calling SubmitChanges() for every InsertOnSubmit() in a case like that would hours, just calling SubmitChanges() right at the end would reduce the time takes to insert that many records to a couple of minutes.

In the case i described above, the arrangement i had was for reporting tables with a header table, details table (which linked to header) and an atom table (which linked to details).  For every header record, i had multiple detail tables which would then again be linked by multiple atom records.  In some cases, i'd end up inserting gazillions of records and they'd all go in no problems with the single SubmitChanges() call at the end and it all performed very well.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any "Guidelines" per-say. Id would say for efficiency you'd want to collect a bunch, maybe not 10k, but say 100? That would drastically reduce your DB Queries and shouldn't eat up too much ram caching them locally while you build up a transaction.

You should probably test with a couple different values and profile the performance (memory & speed) to find the optimal solution for your hardware though.